# Javascript revealing module pattern - variable doest change

Tags: javascript, module

im using slightly modified revealing module pattern and have some issue with getting public variable value after changing it inside the module. Let's take a look.
Simple module:

```js
const MyModule = (function() {
  let _pretendsToBePublic = '';

  const _module = {
    publicVariable: _pretendsToBePublic,
    init() {
      _pretendsToBePublic = 2;
    },
    change(val) {
      _pretendsToBePublic = val;
    }
  };
  return _module;
})();
MyModule.init();
console.log(MyModule.publicVariable); // ''
MyModule.change(333); //still ''
console.log(MyModule.publicVariable);
```

Did i miss something?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "public variable". What you should do is just use the `_module.publicVariable` property everywhere in place of the `_pretendsToBePublic`  local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the *plain reference* `MyModule.publicVariable` to return the private `_pretendsToBePublic`, you'll need to make it a *getter* instead:

```js
const MyModule = (function () {
    let _pretendsToBePublic = '';

    const _module = {
        get publicVariable() {
          return _pretendsToBePublic;
        },
        init() {
            _pretendsToBePublic = 2;
        },
        change(val) {
            _pretendsToBePublic = val;
        }
    };
    return _module;
})();
MyModule.init();
console.log(MyModule.publicVariable) // 2
MyModule.change(333);
console.log(MyModule.publicVariable) // 333
```

Or you could turn it into a standard function, which makes it clearer to the consumer that you're invoking functionality, rather than just retrieving a plain property:

```js
const MyModule = (function () {
    let _pretendsToBePublic = '';

    const _module = {
        getPublicVariable() {
          return _pretendsToBePublic;
        },
        init() {
            _pretendsToBePublic = 2;
        },
        change(val) {
            _pretendsToBePublic = val;
        }
    };
    return _module;
})();
MyModule.init();
console.log(MyModule.getPublicVariable()) // 2
MyModule.change(333);
console.log(MyModule.getPublicVariable()) // 333
```

Comment: I think i got it, just got confused by this example https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript by Addy Osmany, when he is exposing publicvar in such way i did...  But its just a assign-by-value. Ty sir for making it clear to me